# Column validation for US phone number format

Tags: column, validation

I want to validate the field for US format phone number(478-857-4578). I used the below code, it works fine for all but one scenario.

If I enter only 4 digit number or below than, the error message

> The validation formula has evaluated to an error

is displayed.

But for all other wrong inputs, my custom error message

> Please enter phone number in 214-587-5485 format

is displayed.

I wanted to display my custom error message for all invalid inputs. Do I need to change anything in formula?

Formula:

```
=AND(
LEN([num])=12,
    IF(ISERROR(FIND("-", [num],4)),
        FALSE,
        (FIND("-", [num], 4) = 4)
    ),
    IF(ISERROR(FIND("-", [num],8)),
        FALSE,
        (FIND("-", [num], 8) = 8)
    ),
    IF(ISERROR(1*CONCATENATE(MID([num], 1, 3), MID([num], 5, 3), MID([num], 9, 4))),
        FALSE,
        AND(
            1*CONCATENATE(MID([num], 1, 3), MID([num], 5, 3), MID([num], 9, 4)) > 1000000000,
            1*MID([num], 1, 3) <> 911,
            1*MID([num], 5, 3) <> 911
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not validation, but you can use input mask by adding jquery on newform of list

Below is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='Phone']").mask("(999) 999-9999? Ext.99999");
});
</script>
```

For your requirement, you can replace with below line:

```
$("input[title='Phone']").mask("999-999-9999");
```

For reference: [Input Mask on Textbox](http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/02/input-mask-on-textbox-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and I don't think it will work in most scenarios today anyway.