# Replace comma with hyphen in list column

Tags: 2013, inputformtextbox

I want to add a contact number field, so I am using the inbuilt number field, but it is separating the number with comma, and I want hyphen as a separator.

E.g: 
Format now - `1,234,567,890`.

Format required - `1-234-567-890`

Is it possible using **OOTB** approach?

Comment: You want this in a view or modifying the value itself? For example, you just want to display as `- 1-234-567-890` in some list view. Then you can use CSR

Answer (score 3):

As Atish mentioned, CSR is a nice way to change the "displayForm" or the list itself.

I tied something little different quickly.

You could use a calculated column and replace the "," with "-".

But the ***numberlength should be always the same***. Not perfect, but maybe also a possible way for your requirement. Here how I did it:

**Listview with calculated column:**

[image]

**Formula:** =TEXT(Number,"0-000-000-000")

[image]

Comment: typo in `Formular`. **numberlength should be always the same.** as it's a contact no.

Answer (score 1):

this has already been answered:

[Column validation for US phone number format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149106/column-validation-for-us-phone-number-format)

DVWP that you add to the new form

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='Phone']").mask("9-999-999-999");
});
</script>
```

you need to also add it to the edit form

Answer (score 1):

Every possible solution has been added. So why not **CSR**. Execute following code  in the `OnPreRender`

For **AllItems** view

```
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(item){
  item.Number= item.Number.replace(/,/g,"-");
  });
```

For **DisplayForm**

```
ctx.ListData.Items[0].Number= ctx.ListData.Items[0].Number.replace(/,/g,"-");
```

Use [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) for **CSR** development. Benefits of **Cisar**

1. It will generate the boilerplate of **JSLink**
2. Live code edit in console
3. Live test
4. Auto deployment

Comment: Just curious.. have you checked this.. I presume Number is a .. Number .. and does not contain commas.. Its SharePoint who adds the formatting

Comment: I have checked it in my SPO site. It contains comma. In `ctx.ListData.Row`, there are two properties like `Number` and `Number.` `Number` contains the formatted string and `Number.` contains the only number. **PS:** Number is my column name also @DannyEngelman

Comment: Indeed.. CurrentItem gives ``FieldName`` as formatted string, and ``FieldName.`` (with dot) as unformatted number (as a string)... I hate  Microsoft programmers sometimes... that means you can only get the value with string-notation: ``CurrentItem["Number."]``

Comment: PS. You should not do it in the OnPreRender.. It will break any (later added) code that relies on OOB functionality. A View Template for your Number field is a better place...just as much code

Comment: Yeah... It means I am modifying `ctx.ListData.Row` itself. I hope **OP** will do it if he is interested.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Patrick for using the (lesser known) TEXT function to format a number

Here is the Calculated Formula for Number lengths 1 to 10, in a VIEW or DisplayForm

```
=TEXT(123456
      ,CHOOSE(
              LEN(123456)
              ,"0"
              ,"00"
              ,"000"
              ,"0-000"
              ,"00-000"
              ,"000-000"
              ,"0-000-000"
              ,"00-000-000"
              ,"000-000-000"
              ,"0-000-000-000"))
```

*Replace both 123456 with your Number field reference*