# Phone number column validation

Tags: column, validation

I want to add phone number column with below format:

`1-121-343-6917`, `434-5503` & `60-12-444 444`

Used below method

[image]
[image]

`=TEXT(123456
      ,CHOOSE(
              LEN(123456)
              ,"0"
              ,"00"
              ,"000"
              ,"0-000"
              ,"00-000"
              ,"000-000"
              ,"0-000-000"
              ,"00-000-000"
              ,"000-000-000"
              ,"0-000-000-000"))`

But this troublesome when you input information in EDIT mode rather than add NEW ITEM.

How I can use validation? Need help urgently.

Comment: Using what Column validation, c# or js? for C# and JS, use Regex.

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149106/column-validation-for-us-phone-number-format

Comment: Do you want it in SharePoint list column? Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Yes, I want in SharePoint 2013 list column.. I cannot use any scripts or queries as that has been prohibited..

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and Jquery to validate for phone number field.

```
function ValidatePhone() {
    var phoneRegExp = /^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}$/;
    var phoneVal = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var numbers = phoneVal.split("").lengthif (10 <= numbers && numbers <= 20 && phoneRegExp.test(phoneVal)) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }
    }
```

More reference:
[Phone number Validation using Jquery](https://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/phone-number-validation-using-jquery/)