# input mask for textbox in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, jquery

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 and
i want to add date mask to specific text box  on the new form "dd\mm\yyyy"

how can i make masked textbox for date

thanks

Comment: Read about client side rendering (CSR) and regular expressions, you might also find a similar problem solved in other's questions here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below script for input mask on textbox:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://jquery-joshbush.googlecode.com/files/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
   $("input[title='FieldName']").mask("99\99\9999");
});
</script>
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Here is the link for more reference.
[Column validation for US phone number format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149106/column-validation-for-us-phone-number-format)

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSLink to achieve the functionality.

There are four to five function you can write by overriding to achieve that.

> ‘View’ function to render the field if it is included in a list view. In this function you return html.
>
> ‘DisplayForm’ function to render the field when the user is viewing the properties of a list item. Also returns html.
>
> ‘EditForm’ function to render the field when the user is editing the properties of a list item. Returns html.
>
> ‘NewForm’ function to render the field when the user is adding a new list item. Again, should return html. Normally this would be the same as the ‘EditForm’ but it doesn’t have to be.
>
> ‘GetValueCallBack’ function to pass the field’s value to SharePoint after the user clicks Submit. This one should return the value type of the field type. In my example, I’ll return a string value.

Details are described in [**this article**](http://www.lestersconyers.com/custom-field-rendering-with-jslink/).

Answer (score 0):

standard SharePoint Field Validation rules are SharePoint (Calculated) Formulas

So you could check for (*something like*)

- =TEXT( [field] , "dd\mm\yyyy" )

All available functions: 
http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List