# SharePoint 2013 How to make column validation check for a specific pattern?

Tags: 2013, column-validation

I'm trying to create a record repository that will allow a single user the ability to manage uploaded documents based on a record disposal rule system.

I need a column to validate that the uploaded document has a record rule from our system attached to it.

Record rules follow the format: "T ## - ## R ##.##"

How can I make a single line of text column validate that the text entered is in that specific format?
 The # should equal any number 0-9.

Comment: You can use input mask on single line of text. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149106/column-validation-for-us-phone-number-format

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to tell you the exact formula for your requirement. But use below links for reference which includes some more complex examples of column validations:

1. [SharePoint 2010 Column Validation](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-use-or-type-options-in-sharepoint-2010-column-validation/).
2. [SharePoint Column Validation Examples](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html).

**Another Approach**:

Use javascript regular expressions to validate your field using **PreSaveAction** on forms. According to me, this will be quickest way do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this... here's one.

If you want to add a Calculated Column with a message:

```
=IF(
   AND(
     LEN(TheColumn)=17,
     LEFT(TheColumn,2)="T ",
     MID(TheColumn,5,3)=" - ",
     MID(TheColumn,10,3)=" R ",
     ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,3,2)),
     ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,8,2)),
     ISNUMBER(0+RIGHT(TheColumn,5))
   ), "OK", "Invalid code")
```

If you want a validation formula, just remove the IF. The AND will return either True or False.

```
AND(
  LEN(TheColumn)=17,
  LEFT(TheColumn,2)="T ",
  MID(TheColumn,5,3)=" - ",
  MID(TheColumn,10,3)=" R ",
  ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,3,2)),
  ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,8,2)),
  ISNUMBER(0+RIGHT(TheColumn,5))
)
```

If the decimal point is required to be in the third position only then:

```
=IF(
   AND(
     LEN(TheColumn)=17,
     LEFT(TheColumn,2)="T ",
     MID(TheColumn,5,3)=" - ",
     MID(TheColumn,10,3)=" R ",
     MID(TheColumn,15,1)=".",
     ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,3,2)),
     ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,8,2)),
     ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,13,2)),
     ISNUMBER(0+RIGHT(TheColumn,2))
   ), "OK", "Invalid code")
```

or as a validation:

```
AND(
  LEN(TheColumn)=17,
  LEFT(TheColumn,2)="T ",
  MID(TheColumn,5,3)=" - ",
  MID(TheColumn,10,3)=" R ",
  MID(TheColumn,15,1)=".",
  ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,3,2)),
  ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,8,2)),
  ISNUMBER(0+MID(TheColumn,13,2)),
  ISNUMBER(0+RIGHT(TheColumn,2))
)
```